# how to assign null values between 2 rows of a single column

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I am using this case statement to assign curr.course_enrolment_id null between two values of a single row.
it throws an error stating - Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "null"

and (case when curr.unit_start_tp like '%QT%' and prev.unit_start_tp like '%TP%' then curr.course_enrolment_id between curr.unit_start_tp and prev.unit_start_tp is null)

I am trying to assign curr.course_enrolment_id null between two row values of a single column.

Comment: case when cqan only return scalr values, not statemens, why ot post data and wanted result, to see what you are trying to achieve with  your query

Comment: I added a image for your reference, I want course_enrolment_id to be null for, when a student moves from TP courses to QT courses

Comment: Images are not allowed here see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query